# InputStream останавливает приложение при чтении с Bluetooth через input.read()

Tags: java, android, input, bluetooth

Пытаюсь прочитать информацию, отправляемую на телефон по блютуз модулю HC-06. Использую нижеописанный код. Но каждый раз, когда происходит btThread.start() и код доходит до строки input.read(), приложение останавливается. 
Ошибки нет, приложение не падает, но ничего не происходит и нажать ничего нельзя. Похоже на остановку главного потока, но я же запуска input.read() в отдельном.

```
public class FragmentInfoControl extends Fragment {
    private BluetoothSocket socket;
    private Handler handler;
    private StringBuilder stringBuilder;
    private Button bSendMessage;



@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    RelativeLayout parent = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_info_control, container, false);
    NestedScrollView scrollInfo = parent.findViewById(R.id.nsv_all_info);
    ScrollView nsvButtons = parent.findViewById(R.id.nsv_buttons_command);

    final ThreadBT  btTread = new ThreadBT(socket);
    btTread.run();



    final TextView textView = parent.findViewById(R.id.tv_result);


    handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            byte[] readBuffer = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            String result = new String(readBuffer, 0, msg.arg1);
            stringBuilder.append(result);
            Log.i("checkMessage", stringBuilder.toString());
            textView.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
        }
    };

    LinearLayout linearButtons = new LinearLayout(getContext());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    linearButtons.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    linearButtons.setLayoutParams(params);

    final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsButton = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int) (50 * scale + 0.5f),
            (int) (60 * scale + 0.5f));
    paramsButton.bottomMargin=10;
    paramsButton.topMargin = 10;
    paramsButton.setMarginEnd(10);
    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        final Button b = new Button(getContext());
        b.setLayoutParams(paramsButton);
        b.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d5e9f1"));
        if(i == 10) {
            b.setText("s");
        } else if(i == 11) {
            b.setText("f");
        } else {
            b.setText(Integer.toString(i));
        }

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                btTread.write(b.getText().toString().getBytes());

            }
        });

       linearButtons.addView(b);
    }
    nsvButtons.addView(linearButtons);

    return parent;
}


public void setSocket(BluetoothSocket mySocket) {
    socket = mySocket;
}

private class ThreadBT extends Thread {
    private final InputStream input;
    private final OutputStream out;
    private BluetoothSocket socket;
    private Handler handler;

    public ThreadBT(BluetoothSocket socket1) {
        socket = socket1;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;
        try{
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            Log.i("sendMessage",  "1");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("sendMessage", "errooooooooor");
        }

        input = tmpIn;
        out = tmpOut;

    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.i("sendMessage", "2");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesCount;

           try{
               while(true) {
                   if(input.available() > 0) {
                       bytesCount = input.read();
                       String str = new String(buffer);
                       Log.i("sendMessage", "lol" + str);
                   }

               }

           } catch(IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();

           }
        }



    public void write(byte[] msg) {
        try{
            Log.i("sendMessage", new String(msg));
            out.write(msg);
        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }


}
```

}

Пересмотрел всю документацию, что нашел. Вроде делаю все как в примере, но не выходит.

Comment: Как сокет получаете? Через либу или сами пилили работу с bluettoth?

Comment: `btTread.run();` - возможно вы хотели написать `btTread.start();`

Comment: @zRrr да, описался. А в чем разница подскажите?

Comment: `start` запускает новый поток и в нем выполняет метод `run`.

Answer (score 0):

Перенес код класса ThreadBT в Activity, там создал объект класса и запустил поток TreadBT.start(). Все заработало.

Когда запускал поток во фрагменте, код фрагмента переставал выполняться. То есть такой эффект, будто новый поток начинает выполняться в потоке кода фрагмента. Когда запустил поток из Activity, такая проблема пропала.

Проблема решена, только не совсем понимаю, почему это происходило именно так. Буду рад, если кто-то объяснит.